# Интеграция формы в Modx с Битрикс 24 при помощи вебхука. В некоторых случаях не срабатывает сниппет

Tags: modx, битрикс24

Создаю сниппет и вебхук по инструкции отсюда https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/marketplace_apps24/easy-integration-with-bitrix24-or-magic-vibhuti.php

Не могу понять, почему если в action=mail.php задан mail.php, благодаря которому из формы происходит отправка уведомления на электронную почту, то в битрикс данные из формы не поступают. Если же убрать этот action, то данные из формы в битрикс отправляются. Почему такое может происходить и как можно это исправить?

Comment: Покажите ваш сниппет/код пожалуйста, который реализует отправку. Formit не используете совсем?

Comment: @AntonTarasov спасибо что уделили внимание моему вопросу, я решил его, отказавшись от сниппета и поместив функцию из него в php файл. А для чего нужен Formit, я встречал упоминания о нем в других инструкциях, но так и не понял, что он дает.